# Rxjs - block subsequent requests while waiting for method to execute

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, race-condition

I have a class, `UserPermissionsService`, that makes a server request when it's initially accessed. Once the request completes, subsequent calls use the data that's stored in a `BehaviorSubject` to complete their operations. However, if multiple happen simultaneously, the `init` method won't have completed and multiple server requests will occur.

How can I refactor the below class to force subsequent calls to wait for the initial `init` request to complete prior to executing?

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserPermissionsService implements OnDestroy{
  private _permissions = new BehaviorSubject<AppliedPermissions>(null);
  public permissionSnapshot: AppliedPermissions;
  public permissions: Observable<AppliedPermissions> = this._permissions.asObservable();

  constructor(private _userService: UserService) {
  }

  init(): Observable<AppliedPermissions> {
    return this._userService.getPermissions()
      .pipe(tap(p => {
        this._permissions.next(p)
        this.permissionSnapshot = p;
      }));
  }

  hasPermission(permission: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this._permissions.pipe(
      switchMap(value => value ? of(value) : this.init()),
      map(response => {
        const perm = response.permissions
          .find(el => el.permissionName === permission);

        if (!perm)
          return false;

        return perm.allow;
      }),
      catchError(_ => of(false))
    );
  }

  inRole(role: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this._permissions.pipe(
      switchMap(value => value ? of(value) : this.init()),
      map(response => {
        return !!response.roles.find(el => el === role);
      }),
      catchError(_ => of(false))
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this._permissions?.complete();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

did you consider `OnInit()`

```
export class App implements OnInit {
  constructor() {
     // Called first time before the ngOnInit()
  }    
  ngOnInit() {
     // Called after the constructor and called after the first ngOnChanges() 
  }
}
```

---

Now to your answer - try `flatmap` to preserve/control the sequence, this ensures that the order of execution is retained. for e.g. see here

```
first
  .flatMap(() => second)
  .flatMap(() => third)
  .subscribe(()=> console.log('finished'));
```

---

Another option

```
// use this wrapper 
function WaitForComplete<T>(signal: Observable<any>) {
    return (sourceInit: Observable<T>) => signal.pipe(
        first(), switchMap(_ => sourceInit),
    );
}

// force the waiting to complete, by deferring the subscribe on the first source 
// till the signal observable completes/emits (many versions of this out there)
var YourSecond = 
  anotherObservable.pipe(WaitForComplete(YourFirstObservableFunction), take(1));
```

---

Update: [services](https://medium.com/swlh/a-less-known-life-cycle-method-in-angular-services-f9d6e51632d9) can implement `ngOnInit()`

[image]

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, angular services don't receive the `OnInit` lifecycle hook. I could potentially move the code into the constructor, but I'm mostly trying to wait until it's called before loading the data.

Comment: you have to import it from core, and then you can implement it here is a link showing you https://medium.com/swlh/a-less-known-life-cycle-method-in-angular-services-f9d6e51632d9

Comment: can you upvote or mark if it works for you

Comment: It still doesn't quite solve the issue, but it's a step in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would personally replace:

```
switchMap(value => value ? of(value) : this.init()),
```

wirth

```
filter(value=>!!value)
```

Assuming that you want to do the request only in initial init and just  wait for it to finish